# How to add an SVG image to input type=checkbox in React with Styled Components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

Having the following input of type check:

```
export const StyledSelectionBoxInput = styled.input`
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  background-color: ${darkColors.background.dark};
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  border: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.border.dropdown};
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  transition: border-color 100ms, background-color 100ms;
  &:checked {
    background-color: ${darkColors.success.toggle};
  }
  &:hover {
    border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.grey[400]};
  }
  &:focus {
    border-color: ${darkColors.info.main};
  }
`;
```

I want to add an SVG image on it so when it's clicked it will show that SVG in checked state so inside `&:checked`.

```
  import { ReactComponent as CheckIcon } from 'svgs/states/check-solid.svg';

  ...

  &:checked {
    background-color: ${darkColors.success.toggle};
    background-image: url(${IconChecked}); // added here
  }
```

It doesn't work, same behaviour as before and in console it has a warning message saying:

> SvgCheckSolid is not a styled component and cannot be referred to via
> component selector. See
> https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components
> for more details.

How can it be fixed and show an SVG image when input is checked?

This is how the component is used:

```
<StyledSelectionBoxInput
  type="checkbox"
  name={option.name}
  value={option.value}
  id={option.value}
  checked={checked}
  {...rest}
/>
```

Comment: a method for customize an input is hide it and use the `label` instead

Comment: @AbbasBagheri can you give more details?

Comment: this link may help you : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp